# Passing more than two parameter in onclick function in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a problem with the syntax in passing more than two parameter in onclick function which is the **drawStockList**. All I want is pass the value of RRNo, DateReived, Status and Remarks.. The problem is the **comma(,)**.

Here's my code.

```
"aoColumnDefs": [

                {
                    "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<a id="txtRRNo" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="drawStockList('+ row.RRNo + ',' + row.DateReceived + ',' + row.Status + ',' + row.Remarks + ');">' + row.RRNo + '</a>'
                    }, "aTargets": [0]
                },
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the variables you are using are string right? So you should included escaped quotation in your string. You can do that by using backslashes \'

```
"aoColumnDefs": [

               {
                   "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                       return '<a id="txtRRNo" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="drawStockList('+ row.RRNo + ', \'' + row.DateReceived + '\' , \'' + row.Status + ' \', \'' + row.Remarks + '\');">' + row.RRNo + '</a>'
                   }, "aTargets": [0]
               },
```

Comment: Great! This is what I'm looking for. It's working now. Ikaw nag gitagna sa bolang crystal.. Thanks a lot.